# Linux: how to force a USB device to use the same ttyUSB number

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port, usb

I have an USB modem that I use on Ubuntu. I have also a program which communicate with this device using its `ttyUSBxx` number.

My problem is that every time I unplug/plug the device again, or when I reboot my PC, the device gets a new `ttyUSB` number, for example: `ttyUSB0` or `ttyUSB1`.

How can I force this device to always use the same number (say: `ttyUSB0`)?

Answer (score 15):

`udev` is Linux's dynamic device manager. `udev` persists information about devices you plug in, and you can modify this information so that it adds a specific 'symlink' in the directory for this device.

Now, your usb modem's definition should be inside the folder `/etc/udev/rules.d/`, and the filename will be something like `50-udev.rules`. The file contains one line per device, (you can use a number of tools to help identify the correct line. See below link on using `udevinfo`)

Now, you can edit the relevant line, or even better, create another file and copy the relevant line into it. The filename should start with a lower number (e.g. `49-my-modem.rules`), so that it gets loaded first. You need to add the following to the end of the line:

```
, SYMLINK="ttyUSBmodem"
```

Now, your device should come up as `/dev/ttyUSBmodem` (aswell as the dynamically assinged /dev/ttyUSB[0-9])

For more help with identifying the correct line and the whole process, see here:
http://noctis.de/archives/16-HowTo-fixed-name-for-a-udev-device.html

HTH